# React Redux Form checkbox and dropdown field in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux-form

I am trying to build a form in React Native using React Redux Form but I can use the `<TextInput>` for Email & Password but now I would like to use some checkboxes and dropdowns. Their [documentationm](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/) doesn't provide an React Native guideline or any examples as they use simply `<Input>` tag for any inputs but how do i use this in React Native?

Here is my field render I use for email:

```
const renderField = ({ label, type, keyboardType, name, meta: { touched, error }, input: { onChange, ...restInput } }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', height: 70, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 30, alignItems: 'center', borderColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, }}>
        <FontAwesome name='email-outline' size={18} color='#cccccc' style={{ paddingLeft: 2 }} />
        <TextInput style={{ height: 37, width: 280, paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 20 }}
          keyboardType={keyboardType} onChangeText={onChange} {...restInput}
          placeholder={label}
        >
        </TextInput>
      </View>
      {touched && ((error && <Text style={{ color: 'red', }}>{error}</Text>))}
    </View>);
}; 

<Field keyboardType='email-address' type='email' label='Email' component={renderField} name='email' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what's the problem?

Just create a `checkboxField` component that you'll use instead of `renderField` in the places you need. And simply use the `onChange` function from the props to set a `value` and value as the value itself.

Here is an example that would be easier to understand:

```
const renderField = ({ input: { onChange, value } }) => {
   return (
      <View>
         <Switch 
           onValueChange={(value) => onChange(value)} 
           value={value} 
         /> 
      </View>
   );
};
```